# Windows: Run PHP via command line from htdocs

Tags: windows-7, command-line, php

I'm trying to run PHP via the command line (Windows 7), however it's a pain tuping the full path to PHP every time. I tried using mklink

```
mklink /D "c:\xampp\php\php" php
```

however that doesn't seem to have done the trick, it just tells me when I type `php` that it's not a recognised program or command...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `c:\xampp\php` to your `PATH` environment variable.  See here:

[How to set the path in Windows 7](https://web.archive.org/web/20210213041100/http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx)